# Where near Melbourne Victoria Australia can I see snow without needing chains?

Tags: australia, snow

I want to take the kids to see the snow but I don't want to stay overnight and Ideally, I want them to have a play but without having to be too involved such as getting chains on the car or staying overnight.

This is based on the greater Melbourne area in Victoria Australia.

Comment: Just for future visitors, check when there is a big storm because there can also be snow on mount macedon which is closest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere like [Mt Buller](https://www.mtbuller.com.au/) can be an option - about three hours drive from Melbourne, it only requires snow chains under some conditions:

> Wheel chains
>
> If you're driving to Mt Buller and staying overnight, you
> will need to carry wheel chains by law. If you're visiting for the
> day, you may or may not need to carry chains depending on snow and
> road conditions. The daily wheel chain declaration is made each
> afternoon and is communicated via a number of channels - [click
> here](http://mtbuller.com.au/Winter/snow-weather/snow-report/wheel-chains?_ga=2.71488659.1473216690.1530061515-1236306766.1530061513) to view the current wheel chain declaration.

http://www.mtbuller.com.au/Winter/plan-your-visit/first-timers-guide

You can also [catch a coach to and from Mt Buller](https://www.mtbuller.com.au/Winter/plan-your-visit/getting-here/coach) without needing to drive at all and hence not needing chains.  The times allow the majority of the day to be spent at the snow.

[Mt Donna Buang](https://visityarravalley.com.au/mt-donna-buang) is closer to Melbourne (less than 100 km away), frequently has snow, and doesn't necessarily need chains but are recommended:

> Chains? Not usually needed but a good idea to have. No business in
> Warburton supplies chains. As a gazetted road, VicRoads maintain and
> grade snow from the roads and carparks - generally sufficient to get
> vehicles without chains to the carparks. But if you have chains bring
> them. Note there is no guarantee that 2WD vehicles will have access to
> a mountain of snow. Chains and/ or 4WD are best - or seek advice
> locally about conditions before heading up.

https://www.warburtoninfo.com/mount-donna-buang-snow-report.html